# Removing duplicate values in one column based on group of values in another column in power query

Tags: excel, duplicates, powerquery

I have a query in Power Query Editor that has everything i need. However, due to splitting columns and other steps within the process, i have duplicate values in a column that hyper inflates my numbers. Is there an applied step that i can add to the end of my query that will remove duplicate values in "Column 4" based on the value in "Column 5". Column 5 is a unique ID and i only need the first value under Column 4 based on the ID.

The example below is just a small example as my current output has 51 columns and quite a bit of applied steps in the current query.

[image]

duplicates overall in the column are okay, but cannot have duplicates based on the value in another column and the basic remove duplicates removes all.

Comment: Have you tried creating a step and entering manually "= Table.Distinct(PreviousStep)"? (previousstep will be the name of the previous step, e.g. Source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A relatively simple way. Keeps the first non-blank for Column4

```
#"PriorStepName" = .............,
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"PriorStepName", {"Column5"}, {{"data", each 
    let a = _,
    b = Table.RemoveColumns(a,{"Column4"}),
    c = {{List.RemoveNulls(a[Column4]){0}}},
    d = Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(b) & c,Table.ColumnNames(b)&{"Column4"})
    in d , type table }}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Column5"}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "data", Table.ColumnNames(#"PriorStepName"),Table.ColumnNames(#"PriorStepName"))
in  #"Expanded data"
```

[image]

Comment: Since i am copying this into a query with code already, would the first line be needed?

Comment: Thanks, when i close and save i get an expression error: The column 'data' of the table wasn't found. Details: data        could this be related to the "data" on the 2nd row of the code?   in the advance editor it does show No syntax errors have been detected

Comment: are you able to provide the code you previously provided. it seems to work if i dont add it to the bottom of my query but just reference that query into a new query.